# Make throws errors for the Andengine multiplayer extension, but they don't show up in the Intellij IDEA editor window

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, andengine

I am trying to run the [Andengine](http://www.andengine.org/) examples in the IntelliJ IDEA. I managed to import all the necessary extensions and the editor window doesn't show any errors anymore, but when I try to run the project and it compiles all of the classes it shows several errors:

```
/home/mathias/Arbeitsplatz/andenginemultiplayerextension/src/org/anddev/andengine/extension/multiplayer/protocol/server/SocketServerDiscoveryServer.java
  cannot find symbol class IDiscoveryData
/home/mathias/Arbeitsplatz/andenginemultiplayerextension/src/org/anddev/andengine/extension/multiplayer/protocol/server/SocketServer.java
  cannot find symbol class IServerListener
  ... and so on
```

It seems the library can't find some of its own classes, although they are all there, and there are no errors shown in the editor.

I found [this issue on the project page](http://code.google.com/p/andenginemultiplayerextension/issues/detail?id=2) which shows the same errors in eclipse, although I found no description on how to fix it.

I have no custom build settings for this project and all I do is click on the "Run"-Button.

Comment: I have this same problem.  Any solutions?

Comment: According to http://code.google.com/p/andenginemultiplayerextension/issues/detail?id=2, the code depends on several eclipse-specific compile features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is solution from here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79464  :

Same error here with intellij 11.0.2, though a quick patch I found is to set intellij to use Eclipse compiler in the settings/compiler menu (there are several options) and everything seems to compile properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a solution I found elsewhere - set IntelliJ to use the Eclipse compiler.